# Can I apply the absorption law here?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The absorption law is as:

```
p ∨ (p ∧ q) ≡ p
p ∧ (p ∨ q) ≡ p
```

It looks like `q` doesn't matter.

```
p ∨ (p ∧ ~q) ≡ p
p ∧ (p ∨ ~q) ≡ p
```

I've constructed true tables for both and they all check out:

```
p | q | p v (p ^ ~q) | p v (p ^ q)
T | T | T            | T
T | F | T            | T
F | T | F            | F
F | F | F            | F
```

---

So I was wondering if it was OK to use the law when `~q` or even if there is anything else there, for example:

```
p v (p ^ ( p v q v q  )) ≡ p
p v (p ^ ( -anything- )) ≡ p
```

Can I do this in a proof? Or are there any intermediate steps I need to show?

Comment: Exactly. As @5xum explains in his answer. $q$ can be —anything—. If you think of this in terms of Boolean algebras of sets, where $\lor, \land$ are $\cup, \cap$ respectively, then $p$ is always a subset of $p\cup q$, so  $p\cap (p\cup q) = p$ always. Similarly/dually, $p\cap q \subseteq p$, so $p \cup (p\cap q) = p$ always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absorption law says that $p\lor (p\land q)$ is equal to $p$ **no matter what $q$ is**. In particular, you can replace $q$ with $(r\lor(s\land t))$, and the expression will still be equal to $p$.

In your case, you can also replace $q$ with $\neg q$ and the expression is still equal to $p$.

---

If you want, you can also say that the absorption law says that $p\lor(p\land r)$ is always equal to $p$, and then simply set $r=\neg q$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $\land$ and $\lor$ as $+$ and $\times$ with each of them being distributive over the other : $a\land (b\lor c) \equiv a\times (b+c)=(a\times b)+(a\times c),$ and $a\lor (b\land c)\equiv a+(b\times c)=(a+b)\times (a+c).$ Also  $a+a=a\times a=a=a\times 1$ where $1$ is "True". Also $a+1=1.$ We  also use $0$ for "False" with $a+0=a$ and $a\times 0=0.$  $$1\bullet... p\lor (p\land q) 
\equiv p+(p\times q)= (p\times 1)+(p\times q)=p\times (1+q)=p\times 1=p.$$      $$2\bullet ...p\land ( p\lor q)\equiv p\times(p+ q)=(p+ 0)\times (p+q)=p+(0\times q)=p+0=p.$$  We get 2. from 1. by interchanging $+$ and $\times$ and changing $1$ to $0$.